# How to move PDF files in sub-folders according to their file name

Tags: batch-file

I have 376140 PDF files in one folder. I want to move them to sub folders by their name. Since every PDF file is named `SNxxxxxx` (from `SN000001` and onward). I want every 100.000 to be in a sub folder and 10.000 to be a sub folder within that sub folder. End result should be:

```
d:\Doc\SN000001-SN100000\SN000001-SN010000\SN000005.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more logical to sort not from `00001 to 10000`, from `10001 to 20000` and so on, but from `00000 to 09999`, from `10000 to 19999` etc.

And it's much easyer to code:

```
for /L %%i in (0,1,9) do (
  for /L %%j in (0,1,9) do (
    if exist SN%%i%%j*.pdf (
      echo md "D:\Doc\SN%%i00000-SN%%i99999\SN%%i%%j0000-SN%%i%%j9999"
      echo move "SN%%i%%j????.pdf" "D:\Doc\SN%%i00000-SN%%i99999\SN%%i%%j0000-SN%%i%%j9999\"
    )
  )
)
```

Remove the `echo`s when the output seems ok.